# Adding columns that are results of (contextual) text mining operations

Tags: r, csv, text-mining, tm

I am working with a data set with ordinal variables as well as a column with text. In general, I would like to add columns that are results of a text mining exercise, maintaining the table structure.

For example, i have imported a CSV file `data-subset.csv` and obtained a data frame called `datacsv`

```
datacsv=read.csv("data-subset.csv", header=TRUE,sep=";")
```

The third column `tekst` contains text. I would like to search for numbers in that text (that will regularly lie between 0 and 1) in the context of "fte" and add these numbers as column `fte`. See:

```
>  luid  titel            tekst
>1 47300 docent wiskunde  De Stichting Openbaar Voortgezet Onderwijs 0,65
                          fte voltijd niveau: havo vwo
>2 43701 docent natuurkunde Speciaal onderwijs fulltime 2015 2016 fte 0,77 Haarlem
>3 43702 assistent        basisonderwijs Amsterdam fte 0,5
```

i have installed packages like `tm` and `quanteda`

`install.packages("tm", "quantada")`
`library ("tm")`
`library ("quanteda")`

Without satisfying results, I have tried to use various `kwic` statements, such as

```
datacsv ["fte"]<- kwic(datacsv$"tekst", "fte", 4)
```

Does anyone know how to mine the text column and add the results as a column (or multiple columns)?

Thanks!

Comment: So it has strings with numbers and you want to extract the numbers? You should include reproducible example in your questions. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I have edited my question. Hopefully it is more usable now.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
library(stringr) 
datacsv$fte <- str_extract_all(sapply(strsplit(datacsv$tekst, "fte "), "[", 2), '\\d+\\.*\\d*')
```

Comment: This is in the right direction. However, the problem I face currently is that other cases contain multiple numbers. So, for example, the variable `tekst` also contains a year. This means that it is essential that R only extracts those numbers that are located around the term 'fte'. 

Please also see that `fte` is located at random positions between cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?

```
    library(dplyr)       
    mutate(datacsv, 
           fte = as.numeric(regmatches(tekst,regexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+", 
                                                     tekst))))
```